# Can Sympy polynomial solver list zeros of a polynomial according to its multiplicity?

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy.solve to solve a polynomial equation. I noticed the roots are only listed as distinct roots, i.e., they are not repeated according to the multiplicities. Is there an option to repeat the roots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sympy.roots` to get a dictionary in the format `{root:multiplicity, ...}`

```
from sympy import roots, Symbol

x = Symbol("x")
print(roots(x**2 -2*x + 1))
print(roots((x-1)**7 * (x-5)**3 * (x-3)))
```

Output:

```
{1:2}
{3: 1, 5: 3, 1: 7}
```